# Getting text from text boxes on tab control

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, t-sql

I have a form with a **tabcontrol** in it with **4 tabpages** each has it's **own** texboxes and comboboxes, then I have a button **outside** of the tabcontrol wich builds a **SQL** string from all the values entered in these boxes even if some are left blank, the issue is that when i press the button i get a **null reference exception** and even when I use **Try..Catch** or **on error resume next** the compiler refuses to create the text string.
here is the code I have:

```vb
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles btnUpdate.Click
    If Me.BankGuidTextBox.Text = vbNullString Then
        Me.BankGuidTextBox.Text = Guid.Empty.ToString
    End If
    If Me.BankNumTextBox.Text = vbNullString Then
        Me.BankNumTextBox.Text = 0
    End If
    If Me.NameTextBox.Text = vbNullString Or Me.CodeTextBox.Text = vbNullString Then
        GoTo outofsub
    End If
    Try
        Dim strSQL3 As String
        strSQL3 = "USE MSILHR" & vbCrLf & _
            "UPDATE employee SET Code = '" & Me.CodeTextBox.Text & "', Name = '" &  Me.NameTextBox.Text & "', Latinname = '" & Me.LatinNameTextBox.Text & "', Barcode = '" & Me.BarcodeTextBox.Text & "', FirstName = '" & Me.FirstNameTextBox.Text & "', LastName = '" & Me.LastNameTextBox.Text & "', idFather = '" & Me.IdFatherTextBox.Text & "', idMother = '" & Me.IdMotherTextBox.Text & "', idBirthDate = '" & Me.IdBirthDateDateTimePicker.Text & "', idBirthplace = '" & Me.IdBirthPlaceTextBox.Text & "', idSex = '" & Me.IdSexComboBox.SelectedValue & "', idMaritalstat = '" & Me.IdMaritalstatComboBox.SelectedValue & "', idSmoker = '" & Me.IdSmokerComboBox.SelectedValue & "', idMilitary = '" & Me.IdMilitaryComboBox.SelectedValue & "', idRegistry = '" & Me.IdRegistryTextBox.Text & "', idNum = '" & Me.IdNumTextBox.Text & "', idAddress = '" & Me.IdAddressTextBox.Text & "', idNationality = '" & Me.IdNationalityTextBox.Text & "', idReligion = '" & Me.IdReligionComboBox.SelectedItem & "', idTel = '" & Me.IdTelTextBox.Text & "', idMobile = '" & Me.IdMobileTextBox.Text & "', idNotes = '" & Me.IdNotesTextBox.Text & "', jStartDate = '" & Me.JStartDateDateTimePicker.Text & "', jQuitDate = '" & Me.JQuitDateDateTimePicker.Text & "', jQuitReason = '" & Me.JQuitReasonTextBox.Text & "', jSocialSec = '" & Me.JSocialSecTextBox.Text & "', jSocialdin = '" & Me.JSocialdinDateTimePicker.Text & "', jSocialdout = '" & Me.JSocialdoutDateTimePicker.Text & "', jHoliday1 = '" & Me.JHoliday1ComboBox.SelectedValue & "', jHoliday2 = '" & Me.JHoliday2ComboBox.SelectedValue & "', jEmpStat = '" & Me.JEmpStatComboBox.SelectedValue & "', jEmail = '" & Me.JEmailTextBox.Text & "', jPrevvacs = '" & Me.JPrevvacsTextBox.Text & "', jAdminvacs = '" & Me.JAdminvacsTextBox.Text & "', jHealthvacs = '" & Me.JHealthvacsTextBox.Text & "', jUnpaidvacs = '" & Me.JUnpaidvacsTextBox.Text & "', DepartmentGuid = '" & Me.DepartmentGuidComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString & "', JobTitleGuid = '" & Me.JobTitleGuidComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString & "',SalarycalctypeGuid = '" & Me.SalarycalctypeGuidComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString & "', TeamGuid = '" & Me.TeamGuidComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString & "', WorkDays = '" & Me.WorkDaysTextBox.Text & "', DaHours = '" & Me.DaHoursTextBox.Text & "', OverTimeHourPrice = '" & Me.OverTimeHourPriceTextBox.Text & "', CutSalary = '" & Me.CutSalaryTextBox.Text & "',BasicSalary = '" & Me.BasicSalaryTextBox.Text & "', SpecialSalary = '" & Me.SpecialSalaryTextBox.Text & "',CurrencyGuid = '" & Me.CurrencyGuidComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString & "', BankGuid = '" & Me.BankGuidTextBox.Text & "', BankNum = '" & Me.BankNumTextBox.Text & "', PeriodGUID = '" & Me.EmpperiodCombo.SelectedValue.ToString & "'" & vbCrLf & _
            "WHERE GUID = '" & Me.GUIDTextBox.Text & "'"

        '"update employee set Picturepath = (select name from types where type = '660')+'\" & Me.NameTextBox.Text & "' where code = '" & Me.CodeTextBox.Text & "' AND Name = '" & Me.NameTextBox.Text & "'"
        Dim dbConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        ' A SqlCommand object is used to execute the SQL commands.
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL3, dbConnection)

        ' Open the connection, execute the command, and close the connection.
        ' It is more efficient to ExecuteNonQuery when data is not being 
        ' returned.
        dbConnection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        dbConnection.Close()

        MessageBox.Show("Record is updated.", _
            "Data Addition Status", _
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    Catch sqlExc As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(sqlExc.ToString, "SQL Exception Error!", _
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
    'Me.EmployeeTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MSILHRDataset.employee)

    ResetUI()
outofsub:
    MsgBox("you need to add more information!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error")
End Sub
```

**Ok new update :** 
I entered some data left some text boxes empty but made sure all combo boxes has values selected in them and then pressed updatebutton I got the same problem, **but** I redid that changed the current tab selected to any other one (from the other four) and then switched back to the previous tab, I press the button and **IT WORKS!!??** it's as if the form doesn't **Commit** the values entered by user until focus changes or something it's crazy.

Comment: You are only catching a SqlException.  You need to also catch a general exception.

Comment: Try to debug line by line and tell as where the error throws. I create a tabcontrol with textboxes and I can get the total string with no problem. Are you? What I mean is that strSQL3 has a value (the value that you expecting)?

Comment: `GoTo outofsub` Aaghr... my eyes...

Comment: In comboboxes when you are filling them have you put something as value? Because you are using selectedValue

Comment: Whats the exact exception? They are usually pretty helpful

Comment: I don't know if it helps or if it's a vital info the I missed telling you but the form controls are **DataBinded!**. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: What happens if the user inputs `'; TRUNCATE TABLE employee;--` in the `Me.CodeTextBox.Text` field? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Wow I guess a disaster happens, but I don't think my users are that brilliant!, cool topic though

Comment: No no wait what ever the text is it's put between '' so it doesn't matter. And I'm still in a problem about the question so please anyone.

Comment: If you are still having problems then break down the string.  Comment out the second two lines and add stuff back in only clause at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only catching a SqlException.
You need to also catch a general exception.

```
Catch sqlExc As SqlException
    MessageBox.Show(sqlExc.ToString, "SQL Exception Error!", _
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
Catch exc As Exception
  MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString, "General Exception Error!", _
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
```

Not sure why you are getting a null exception.
But it is not caught because it is not a SqlException.
On that String break it down do see where it is breaking.
On the surface it looks like it should work.
I suspect one of the controls is returning null rather than string.empty.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip, I updated all of my Try..Catch statements.